# Append variables submitted through POST to a string previously submitted through POST in PHP?

Tags: php, string, post

so, my situation is as follows. I have pizzas that have a price and the user can choose which size the pizza is supposed to have (page1). When the user chooses a size it is submitted (along with the name of the pizza), on the next page the user gets to choose # of toppings based on the size. 2 for small, 3 for large and so on (page2). Since the user can but not necessarily has to choose the maximum amount of toppings, I'm having issues with keeping the data apart.

I basically want to distinguish between the toppings selected for each pizza. Currently I get `array(1) { ["toppings"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "Egg" [1]=> string(6) "Rucola" [2]=> string(6) "Rucola" [3]=> string(5) "Bacon" [4]=> string(10) "Mozzarella" } }`

I would want a string that holds Name of pizza, size, topping1, topping2, topping3, next pizza, size, topping1, topping2, topping3.

Thanks

```
public function arrayIterator($pizzen) {
    $html_table = "";

    foreach($pizzen as $key) {
        $html_table .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($key as $value) {
            if(is_numeric($value)) {
                $html_table .= '<td>' . sprintf('%01.2f', $value) . '</td>';
            } else {
                $html_table .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
                $checkboxValue = $value;
            }
        }
        $html_table .= '<td><select class="selectpicker" name="size[]"><option></option><option name="small" value="' . $checkboxValue . ' small">Small</option>
            <option name="large" value="' . $checkboxValue . ' large">Large</option><option name="xl" value="' . $checkboxValue . ' xl">X-Large</option>
            </select></td><td><label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="' . $checkboxValue . '" /></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted-1"></td></tr>';
    }

    return $html_table;

}

/*
 * printOrderDetails()
 * toppingIterator()
 * belong to page 2 of order process.
 *
 *
 */

public function toppingIterator()
{

    if (($_POST['submitted']) && (count($_POST['ticked']) != null)) {

        $mais = new Toppings(0.50, "Mais");
        $kaese = new Toppings(1.00, "Cheese");
        $ei = new Toppings(0.50, "Egg");
        $rucola = new Toppings(1.00, "Rucola");
        $bacon = new Toppings(1.50, "Bacon");
        $schinken = new Toppings(1.50, "Bacon2");
        $tuna = new Toppings(2.00, "Tuna");
        $knofi = new Toppings(0.80, "Garlic");
        $jalapenos = new Toppings(1.00, "Jalapenos");
        $mozzarella = new Toppings(1.00, "Mozzarella");

        $toppings = array($mais, $kaese, $ei, $rucola, $bacon, $schinken, $tuna, $knofi, $jalapenos, $mozzarella);

        $toppingPrice = 0;
        $maxOptions = 2; // least amount of toppings possible
        $toppingTable = "";

        foreach($_POST['size'] as $key => $sizes) {

            echo $sizes . "<br/>";

        if(strpos($sizes, "small") != 0) {
            $maxOptions = 2;
        } else if (strpos($sizes, "large") != 0) {
            $maxOptions = 3;
        } else if (strpos($sizes, "xl")) {
            $maxOptions = 5;
        }

        if(!empty($sizes)) {

            $toppingTable .= '<th>' . $sizes . '</th><td><select class="selectpicker" name="toppings[]" data-max-options="'
                . $maxOptions . '" multiple>';

            foreach ($toppings as $key) {
                foreach ($key as $value) {
                    if (is_numeric($value)) {
                        $toppingPrice = sprintf('%01.2f', $value);
                    } else {
                        $toppingTable .= '<option name="'
                            . $value . '" value="' . $value . '">'
                            . $value . '(+' . $toppingPrice . 'EUR)' . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            }

            $toppingTable .= '</select></td>';
        } else {

        }
        }
        echo('<form action="bestellen3.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"><table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Toppings</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>' . $toppingTable .
            '</tbody></table><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Abschicken</button></form>');
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to pass information to final form from previous 3 pages or just want to know how to loop your array?

Comment: The former. I want to pass information from the previous pages to the final page, so I can process it there. And i need to be able to distinguish which information from the second page (the toppings) belongs to which from the first page (the pizza).

Comment: You can save your data in $_SESSION to keep it available on all pages. http://php.net/session_start

Comment: I would create a Pizza object/datatype, and use an array of them. And I woudl store it in $_SESSION as Hokascha mentions...